# onStop() called mysteriously after orientation change recreation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, screen-orientation

I dont know why but after the re-creation of activity and fragment in a orientation change the system stops the fragment. Im using tabed fragments at the actionbar with TabListener.

**Log:**

```
09-09 16:49:36.132: I/fraglifecycle(1432): ChatFragment.onCreateView();
09-09 16:49:36.284: I/fraglifecycle(1432): ChatFragment.onServiceConnected();
09-09 16:49:36.288: I/fraglifecycle(1432): recuperando posição da listview: 2
================================= ROTATION ==================================
09-09 16:49:56.928: I/fraglifecycle(1432): onSaveInstanceState()
09-09 16:49:56.932: I/fraglifecycle(1432): ChatFragment.onStop();
09-09 16:49:57.028: I/fraglifecycle(1432): ChatFragment.onCreateView();
09-09 16:49:57.280: I/fraglifecycle(1432): tab selected; mFragment != null, attaching
09-09 16:49:57.284: I/fraglifecycle(1432): ChatFragment.onServiceConnected();
09-09 16:49:57.284: I/fraglifecycle(1432): recuperando posição da listview: 5
09-09 16:49:57.436: I/fraglifecycle(1432): ChatFragment.onStop();
```

**Print before change:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/upk42kjbvgizoe1/Captura%20de%20tela%202014-09-09%2013.54.07.png?dl=0

**Print after change:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mse9z29zk6ou2nr/Captura%20de%20tela%202014-09-09%2013.52.55.png?dl=0

**My Fragment:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    // Em algumas versões do Android, este metódo ocasionará o chamado do
    // metodo onOptionsMenuCreate() imediatamente
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_layout, container, false);

    edittext = (MyEditText) view.findViewById(R.id.chatinput);
    edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

    listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.chatlist);

    bt_send = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sendbutton);
    bt_send.setOnClickListener(this);

    registerForContextMenu(listview);

    // Request service connection

    Intent it = new Intent(activity, MyService.class);

    activity.bindService(it, this, 0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStop() {

    activity.unbindService(this);

    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binderservice) {
          LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) binderservice;
    this.service = binder.getService();

    if (this.isChannel()) {
        conversa = service.getCanalAdapter();
    } else {
        String stringuuid = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_ARGUMENT);
        conversa = service.getPVTAdapter(UUID.fromString(stringuuid));
    }

    listview.setAdapter(conversa);

}
```

**Please help me, im having several problems with the cycle Fragment-Service-Orientation Change and stuck in my developing for more than a month.
Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

From your code and the log, the onStop() is most likely called for the previous activity, not the activity that is being newly recreated.

Comment: What could be causing it? Im newbie in orientation change yet, pls help me.
PS: i already read a lot of things about fragment and activity lifecycle, service connection, orientation change, but i cannot undertand what is happening.

Comment: this is normal life cycle happening. The previous instance of the activity is being stopped and destroyed.

Comment: The fragment isnt detached from the previous activity as soon as it is destroyed? How could it (previous activity) stop the fragment after his own onDestroy()?

Comment: the fragment is detached from the previous activity. but the fragment itself also go through the same kind of life cycle. onStop was probably called on the previous instance of the fragment as well.

Comment: I dont understand. Fragment is destroyed and recreated in orientation change or not?

Comment: Yes it does. Just exactly like the activity

Comment: If it is destroyed, how the destroyed fragment is calling onStop() on new fragment?

Comment: the android system is calling onStop of the old instance of the fragment when it is being destroyed.

Comment: Finally, what should i do to avoid this behavior and correctly apply orientation change in my activity, that haves an actionbar with tabs, and one fragment per tab. Help me pls.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a Fragment:

Use `setRetainInstance(true);` in the `onAttach(Activity activity)` of your Fragment.

That should stop restore the state of the Fragment even when the Activity changes, so your Fragment will be the same.

I believe that should help.

---

```
Open for correction, as always!

Regards,
Edward Quixote.
```

Comment: But i read that:
_setRetainInstance(true): It is recommended to be used with fragments that do not hold any reference to anything, that will be recreated on rotation. This means you should not use it on any Fragment that holds Context, Views, etc. A typical Visual fragment does. But it is very useful to with Fragments that hold objects like running Threads, AsyncTasks, Data Collections, loaded assets, fetched results etc. This method help using a non visual Fragment, as a detachable holder, for non Context-dependent objects of an Activity._